# The difference between Hilbert Scheme and Chow Scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am confused by Hilbert Scheme and Chow Scheme.  Whenever you have a point in hilbert scheme, take its fiber in the universal family and take its fumdamental class, we get a point in Chow Scheme; and if we have a point in Chow scheme, take its fiber and then take its support, we get a point in Hilbert scheme.  I know they should not be the same, but what is the difference between Hilbert scheme and Chow Scheme?

Comment: A given closed subset can have lots of different scheme structures. If you haven't already, try googling "Hilbert-Chow morphism".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Chow variety of $2$ points in $\mathbb P^1$. When the points collide, the support of that cycle is $1$ point. I.e. the map you attempted to define from the Chow variety to "the" Hilbert scheme goes to the wrong Hilbert scheme.

Comment: can we just interpret the support of those two coincide points with multiplicity two?

Comment: Read about the Hilbert scheme of 2 points in the plane.